# Visual Studio c++ net Charting -How to make sync of scroll and zoom on all chart areas?

Tags: c++, .net, charts

I have two chart areas - on chartArea1 2 series, and 1 series on chartArea2. 
How to make a general scroll and zoom for all chart areas?

Comment: I set align chartarea2 to chartarea1, code( http://pastebin.com/Kk3pfi9F)

Comment: Now, if I increase the area of ​​the chart disappears chartarea2 = \. Chart with no zoom -- bottom line--chartarea2, candlstick -chartarea1 nozoom--http://www.ii4.ru/image-468152.html,  with zoom--http://www.ii4.ru/image-468154.html --bottom line is disappears